# Godot 2D Top Down Tile Rendering in a Procedurally Generated World

Tags: rendering, godot, procedural-generation, chunking, gdscript

**I know this question gets asked a lot. But for the life of me I cannot find the answer on the internet.**

So far I have created a Scene with a Player node(camera attached) and a TileMap.

The TileMap uses OpenSimplexNoise to generate a 32x32 grid of tiles around the player, a 'chunk'.

I have created a script to generate new tiles in a _process(Delta) constantly but this destroys the frame rate if the 'chunk' is to large and when I have to update the Bitmask at the same time.

Through my research I understand that rather than updating the tiles every 0.1 second it would be quicker to draw them in 9 'chunks' around the player as they move through the 'chunks'.

I vaguely understand the concept of using the 'chunk' as an instance and duplicating it but it seems like this is only necessary in a 3D scene.

**My Question is:
Do I need to instance a TileMap chunk or can I keep the TileMap in the scene and draw tiles in large chunks depending on the players chunk position.**

My End game here is to create a large finite map generated procedurally but I cannot get past the stage of drawing lots of cells to fill a screen when I am using bitmasks and autotiles.

Any resources, links, tutorials would be so helpful as there is so much knowledge on the internet that I am lost trying to find the right answer.

Here is my code:

```
func _ready():
   randomize()
   noise = OpenSimplexNoise.new() # Makes the noise OpenSimplexNoise
   noise.seed = 123456#randi()
   print("seed: " + str(noise.seed))
   noise.octaves = 1.0
   noise.period = 12
   noise.persistence = 0.7
   screensize = get_viewport().get_visible_rect().size
   addChunk()



func addChunk():
   var chunkWidth = 32
   var chunkHeight = 32
   var player_pos = Vector2(0,0)
   var chunkCenter = ($Grid.world_to_map($Player.position)/32)*32
   var PlayerChunkPos = ($Grid.world_to_map($Player.position)/16)
   var columnStart: float = (chunkCenter.x/16 - (chunkWidth/2)+16)
   var columnEnd: float = (chunkCenter.x/16 + (chunkWidth/2)+16)
   var rowStart: float = (chunkCenter.y/16 - (chunkHeight/2)+16)
   var rowEnd: float = (chunkCenter.y/16 + (chunkHeight/2)+16)
      for x in range(columnStart,columnEnd):
        for y in range(rowStart,rowEnd):
           var a = noise.get_noise_2d(x,y)
              if  a < grass_cap:
                $Grass.set_cell(x,y,0)
                #$Grass.update_bitmask_region(Vector2(0.0, 0.0), Vector2(x,y))


func _process(delta):
   addChunk()
   print($Grid.world_to_map($Player.position))
   print(($Grid.world_to_map($Player.position)/32).floor())
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `TileMap` already handles chunks of tiles for rendering internally. You can configure the size of those chunk by setting [`cell_quadrant_size`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tilemap.html#class-tilemap-property-cell-quadrant-size). So, yes, a single `TileMap` should work for a finite map of reasonably large size.

---

For generating what is in chunks… Well, once a chunk is generated, you don't have to generate it again, do you? So, keep track of what chunks you have generated already (I'd suggest to use the keys of a dictionary as set).

You would use the position of the camera to compute the coordinates of the nearby chunks. For each one, you check if they are in the set of generated chunks. For those chunk are aren't generated, you call a function that generates the chunk given its coordinates, and then them to the set of generated chunks.

---

Possible path for further optimization: You could only generate chunks when the camera moves from chunk to chunk. Furthermore, you could only consider chunks in the same direction from the camera that the camera moved (assuming the camera didn't jump chunks too many chunk).

---

*For further questions, I suggest the sister site [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). There are plenty of existing question about chunks and world generation there that might help you.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I may be confusing myself, as you can see from my code I am using the TileSet $Grass to set the correct cells depending on the noise level as my character moves.

It creates a new set of cells every time the character moves over a new cell, but this causes lag if as it is calling lots of cells per 0.1 seconds.

Are TileSets the wrong way to go about building chunks of tiles on the map? I feel like i'm making a mistake of trying to combine these two things.

Thank you for the link, I will check that out!

Comment: @FumbleTouch `TileMap` can be used for procedural generation (you can find tutorials in YouTube that show this). However, you need to minimize writes to the `TileMap`. As I see it, your code is doing a lot of extra work writing to cells that are already set, and doing it tens of times per second in `_process`. Setting the cells to what they already are is simply wasted effort. You already know this is problematic, because you are getting lag.

Comment: @FumbleTouch There are other solutions, including multiple `TileMap`, or a custom canvas shader, or using sprites instead of tiles (Usually a bad idea)… Perhaps you would find some of those work closer to what you imagine. For example the shader would draw every frame. Or perhaps the idea of writing each cell once is easier for you if you have multiple `TileMap`, each one a chunk. But that does not mean this cannot be done with a single `TileMap`. Perhaps we can even argue a `TileMap` per chunk or the shader are better, as they can handle the infinite map, while keeping memory use bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. Your last comment is where I'm at with my understanding i.e creating a single chunk using TileMaps. I have managed to create a single chunk from 4 TileMaps and my research was pointing me toward instancing this into my scene but I cannot wrap my head around how to instance the chunk to a grid coordinate and for this to work (like you said in your original comment) I need a dictionary or array to store these chunks. There's a lot to understand and I'm finding it hard to get clear information from youtube and forums. 

Thanks you again.

Comment: @FumbleTouch "a single chunk from 4 TileMaps" I would make it 1, perhaps bigger chunk. "I cannot wrap my head around how to instance the chunk to a grid coordinate" Instantiate the `TileMap`, set its position, then add it to the scene. This could help: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/187236/10408 - You can use a [`Dictionary`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_dictionary.html) with the positions (Vector2) as key, use `has` to check if it is already there. For a single `TileMap` I'd just add `true`, and use the keys as set. For multiple `TileMap`, they can be the values.

Comment: I have used 4 TileMaps so I can make use of layering 4 different TileSets that work off different levels of noise, i.e one effects the placement of grass, one makes roads, one adds environment objects and another adds the background tiles. Is this something that can be done in one TileMap or would it be the case of instancing them all separately? Thank you for the link, I will look into how Dictionaries work and how to use them. Thank you again for taking the time to explain all this.

Comment: @FumbleTouch I see, yes in that case each layer would be `TileMap`. You can make a new scene with them, then instantiate that scene.